# Running NPM gives SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: node.js, npm

Using brew on Mac to install Node and NPM. Running npm gives error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
          ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I found some similar questions, but either not exactly like it, or with no solution. So nothing seems to work for me. Any idea?

Comment: which versions are you using? (npm and node)

Comment: Your question made me realize I had old node version that was running instead of recent one. Problem solved now that I dealt with it. Thanks!

Comment: So the problem was the `let` keyword right?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon No. It was that I had two NPMs, one old which was being used instead of the new one. I removed the old one, and set all paths right, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue changed the node js version https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ removed npm folder from appdata and installed